# herokuにデプロイしたNode.jsアプリを外部のPostgreSQLに接続したい

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, ipv6

(https://teratail.com/questions/4sikr3t5bq56l3 にてマルチポストしている質問です。)

#### 実現したいこと

herokuにデプロイしたNode.jsアプリを外部のPostgreSQLに接続したい。

#### 前提

Node.jsでアプリケーションを作成しました。
pgモジュールのPoolを用いて外部のPostgreSQLからデータを取得し、加工した上でまた別のDB (CMS) にデータをPOSTするアプリです。node app.jsで実行されます。

データ取得先のPostgreSQLにはセキュリティのためにIP制限を設けており、特定のIPアドレスからの接続のみ許可するようにしています。

そこで、アプリをherokuにデプロイし、アドオンのProximoを用いて固定IPを取得し、アプリの実行を行いました。

#### 発生している問題

heroku上でnode app.jsを実行しても、外部PostgreSQLに接続ができません。
herokuからProximoの管理画面を開くと、固定IPは表示されており、herokuの環境変数にもPROXIMO_URLが自動生成されています。
Procfileにも「bin/proximo」を記載しています。

#### 試したこと

PostgreSQL側でWiFiのグローバルIPアドレスの接続許可を設定し、ローカル環境でnode app.jsを実行したところ、うまく接続されます。

回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/4sikr3t5bq56l3) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)